# How do you fire 'Correct Indentation' on save in ZeroBrane Studio?

Tags: zerobrane

ZeroBrane has an excellent Lua formatter built in that fires with: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Is there a way to trigger that to fire on save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a plugin to do this using `onEditorPreSave` event or can make it an inline plugin by adding the following to the config file:

```
package {
  onEditorPreSave = function(self, editor)
    ide:GetMainFrame():ProcessEvent(wx.wxCommandEvent(
      wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, ID.REINDENT))
  end,
}
```

This will send a command to process reindentation event, which should have the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you @paul-kulchenko, that was just what I needed!